# CSS mix-blend-mode not working if the background image is placed in another tag

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

I have this simple page layout with a `header` and a `banner`.

I want to make the `header` transparent and sit on top of the `banner` image (which I might convert into a slider later, here for simplicity I have used single image).

The `menu` which is inside `header` is not clearly visible because of the background image, so I decided to use `mix-blend-mode: difference`, as I should.

But the text is not changing color.

As you can see in the below code snippet, I have applied `mix-blend-mode` to the `<a>`. **This only works if I give `li` a background color**.

I think the problem is that the image element is in a different tag that the `mix-blend-mode` element. I cannot figure out where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.header .header__bottom ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

.header .header__bottom ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .header__bottom ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.banner img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <div class="header__bottom">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://www.imltravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IML-LOGO-VECTOR-WEBSITE-SMALL-e1489572911433.png">
    </div>
    <div class="header__menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tour Packages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Visa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="banner">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503220317375-aaad61436b1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8OHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80">
</section>
```

Comment: keep your initial code and only add the logo, otherwise you will make my answer irrelevant

Comment: Oh ok... I'll change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.header` is creating a stacking context since it has `z-index` defined

Either remove z-index:

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.header .header__bottom ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

.header .header__bottom ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .header__bottom ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.banner img {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
 margin:0
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://www.imltravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IML-LOGO-VECTOR-WEBSITE-SMALL-e1489572911433.png">
    </div>
  <div class="header__bottom">
    <div class="header__menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tour Packages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Visa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="banner">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503220317375-aaad61436b1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8OHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80">
</section>
```

Or move the mix-blend-mode to header (but this will affect the logo too):

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  z-index:9;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.header .header__bottom ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

.header .header__bottom ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .header__bottom ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://www.imltravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IML-LOGO-VECTOR-WEBSITE-SMALL-e1489572911433.png">
    </div>
  <div class="header__bottom">
    <div class="header__menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tour Packages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Visa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="banner">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503220317375-aaad61436b1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8OHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80">
</section>
```

> An element that has blending applied, must blend with all the underlying content of the stacking context **that that element belongs to.** <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#csscompositingrules_CSS)</sup>

Comment: Moving the thing to the header helped me in this. z-index is not in my actual code (the one I'm working on). That really helped! But it is also applying to the Logo which really looks bad. Can I exclude elements from mix-blend-mode which is under header?

Comment: Like the logo is all inverted now.

Comment: I have added an extra code snippet above. Thank you!

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul if you consider my first code without z-index, it will work fine